# How to Convert 23456 into string and it should display like "Two Three Four Five Six"?

Tags: string, vb.net, numbers, cpu-word, converters

I need help to convert any given Number say "0123456789" present in TextBox to get converted into string like "Zero One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine" and get printed in VB.Net.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0.02

```
Private Function NumberDigitsToText(Num As Integer) As String
    Dim rv As String = ""
    Dim words() As String = {"Zero ", "One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ", "Five ", "Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine "}

    rv = String.Join("", (From c In Num.ToString
                          Select words(Integer.Parse(c))))
    Return rv
End Function
```

Comment: dbasnett thanks for you Solution It worked , i also want same code for vb6

Answer (score 1):

As Jimi suggested , you can do something like this

```
Dim wordsarray As String() = {"Zero", "One", "Two", " Three" , "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"}
Dim result As String = ""
For each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
  result &= wordsarray(Integer.Parse(c)) & " "
Next
'The string is now stored in the result variable and you can do something like this
Msgbox(result)
```

With this, you must make sure the value of the text box are only integers

Comment: @Jimi Thanks I have edited the answer, can it still be edited further?

Comment: Yes! `Dim numarray As Char()` etc. is not needed. As previously described, a string is already an array of Char: you can simply have `For each c As Char In Textbox1.Text`. Another line goes. If you think that it should be trimmed, add `TextBox1.Text.Trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a function that read until end and for each integer,do a conversion with a table as 1 -> One; 2 -> Two and etcaetera ?

like

```
Dim something as somewhat control that can carry text
Dim converted as other somewhat control that also can carry text

for each char in something.text
if char = ("1") then
converted.text = converted.text & ("one")
elseif char = ("2")
converted.text = converted.text & ("two")
elseif
...
```

sorry for my bad english, hope you see my idea with some quick, dirty and messy idea out of nowhere from my a**

Comment: Put the numbers' names in an array, then use the result of `Integer.Parse(c.ToString())` (or even `Cint()` here) in a `for each` loop to select the name from the array. A StringBuider is better than string concatenation. Or LINQ, in one line.

Comment: @Jimi Wow I like your idea

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
Function NumberToText1(ByVal n As Integer) As String ' numeri da 0 a 9
    Dim arr() As String = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
"Eight", "Nine"}
    Return arr(n) & " "
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim w As String = ""
    For Each s As String In TextBox1.Text
        w += NumberToText1(CInt(s))
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(w)
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each s As String In TextBox1.Text` I don't think this is valid because there is only one string in the textbox.